# Netbeans + servlet

Tags: java

In my J2EE application I use a servlet, but Netbeans doesn't appears to recongnice the libraries javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, or javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, is valid to mention that I use Netbena 6.7...how can I fix the problem??????

Answer (score 1):

Choose **Java Web project** template.

Answer (score 1):

Just like adatapost already said, make sure you started with a project type that's appropriate, like Java Web Web Application.  The tutorials on the Netbeans side are very helpful, you can find the web related tutorials [here](http://www.netbeans.org/kb/trails/web.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. At the time of installation, select customize button and then check both Glassfish and Apache Tomcat.
2. Select Java Web Application while creating new project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Also, you might need the web development related plugins for creating a new 'Java web application'.

The 'Java SE' variant of Netbeans might not be sufficient. Download the complete Java Netbeans IDE (for 238 MB) from [here](http://www.netbeans.org/downloads/index.html)